# Puppet template variable inside another template variable

Tags: ruby, templates, puppet, erb

How do I call a variable from my manifest inside, while of another variable in a template.erb file?

This is what I've tried to do:

```
<%= food[<%= menu %>] %>
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: He means use a hash, which is definitely what you should do given the information provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use the variable, as is:

```
<%= food[menu] %>
```

You're already in "Ruby code space" within the ERB expansion, so you can use Ruby code as you normally would.

Referring to the [Puppet 4.5 Embedded Ruby (ERB) template syntax](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html) section on [Accessing Puppet Variables](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html#accessing-puppet-variables), there are 2 forms of variable access:

- @variable syntax
- scope['variable'] syntax

From the example in the question, there's not enough information to accurately determine the origin of the `food` variable.  This question assumes that it's the result of processing an array or hash manifest variable.  If `food` is the manifest variable, itself, it should be prefaced with `@`, as such:

```
<%= @food[menu] %>
```

If the manifest variable is `foods`, and the `food` variable is an element of the enumerable (Array or Hash), it would be used as such:

```
<%= @foods.each do |food| %>
  <%= @food[menu] %>
<% end %>
```

Stick with the documented methods of accessing the manifest variable, and you can use it in your template exactly as you would within traditional Ruby code.

Comment: Yes.  However, it is preferred for templates to access Puppet variables via the `@var` form.